# Is it possible to wildcard for an attribute name with a wildcarded attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I currently have `[src*=example]` that selects all HTML elements with a 'src' attribute containing 'example'. Is it possible to target any attributes, pretty much resulting in wildcarding for attributes?

More or less, it would be something like `[(any attribute)*=example]` that would find all elements with any attribute containing 'example'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Consider the performance implications. Every attribute of every element in the DOM would need to be tested. This is a feature you don't want. :-)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is this needed for? Seems like there must be a better way to get what you need.

Comment: @sixfingeredman -- (I am still familiarizing myself with JS/jQuery and) attempting to edit or possibly remove some elements on a page

Answer (score 2):

NO. There's no such selector in css up to this date!

---

Using jQuery:

```
$('*').filter(function(){
   var selector = this;
     return $.grep(selector.attributes, function(attr) { 
        return attr.value.indexOf('example') !==-1 }).length > 0;
}).css('color','red');
```

Comment: I may have to take back my upvote if you keep posting those attempts to do what he wants. ;-) If you really want to, you'd iterate the native `.attributes` collection of each element, and test each object's `.name` and `.value`. But seriously, don't. Someone may actually use it! Whatever the OP is trying to do, he's almost certainly taking the wrong approach.

Comment: Example for kicks: `$.each(document.body.attributes, function(i, attr) { console.log(attr.name, attr.value); })`

Comment: Nope, you're doing it wrong. You don't need `.each()` on a single element, and a jQuery object doesn't have an `attributes` property.

Comment: You're getting closer, but the `attributes` is a collection and so you need to test each attribute in the collection. Use `$.grep`.

Comment: `return $.grep(this.attributes, function(attr) { return attr.value === "example"; }) > 0;`. The `$.grep` is just a filter, like `.filter()`. That they didn't call it `$.filter` is bizarre.

Comment: How does that account for the wildcarded value that merely contains 'example' which would work for something like 'http://example.com'?

Comment: `return attr.value.indexOf("example") !== -1`

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: Sorry, I forgot to put `.length` on the end of the `$.grep`, which is needed because it returns the filtered collection.

Comment: My laptop  was running in low battery and suddenly it gone off and could not update.

Comment: and really, learnt something from you. Thank you very much for being so helpful.(Y)